# Create lists of nodes from rows of matching pairs

Tags: python, pandas, merge

*Not sure if this can be done with pandas or if I need to write a loop with some logic.*

I have some data representing chains of pairs of nodes:

```
pairs = [
    # A1 -> B1 -> C1
    {'source': 'A1', 'target': 'B1'},
    {'source': 'B1', 'target': 'C1'},
    # A1 -> D1
    {'source': 'A1', 'target': 'D1'},
    # C2 -> A2 -> B2
    {'source': 'C2', 'target': 'A2'},
    {'source': 'A2', 'target': 'B2'},
]
```

And I want to resolve those chains to create the list of nodes they contain:

```
results = [
    ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'],
    ['C2', 'A2', 'B2'],
]
```

So far I have this code which does allow me to match some of those nodes together:

```
def pair_nodes(df, src, tgt):
    df = df.groupby([src]).agg({tgt: 'unique'}).reset_index()
    df['nodes'] = df.apply(lambda r: np.append(r[src], r[tgt]), axis=1)
    return df


df1 = pair_nodes(df, 'source', 'target')
df2 = pair_nodes(df, 'target', 'source')
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Which gives me:

```
  source    target         nodes
0     A1  [B1, D1]  [A1, B1, D1]
1     A2      [B2]      [A2, B2]
2     B1      [C1]      [B1, C1]
3     C2      [A2]      [C2, A2]
  target source     nodes
0     A2   [C2]  [A2, C2]
1     B1   [A1]  [B1, A1]
2     B2   [A2]  [B2, A2]
3     C1   [B1]  [C1, B1]
4     D1   [A1]  [D1, A1]
```

And I'm a stuck there. What I guess I'm missing is to **merge `rows` from `df1` and `df2` whenever `source` or `target` is found in `nodes`**

I had a look at [df.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) but it only seems to work for exact key match.

**Can this be achieved with pandas or do I need to write a custom loop/logic to do this?**

Comment: I would suggest to use a dictionary or adjacency list of graphs and doing graph traversals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the desired result with merging dataframes can be a complicated process.
The above used login of merging will not be able to satisfy all types of graphs. Have a look at the below method.

```
# Create graph
graph = {}
for pair in pairs:
    if pair['source'] in graph.keys():
        graph[pair['source']].append(pair['target'])
    else:
        graph[pair['source']] = [pair['target']]

# Graph
print(graph)
{
    'A1': ['B1', 'D1'], 
    'B1': ['C1'], 
    'C2': ['A2'], 
    'A2': ['B2']
}

# Generating list of nodes
start = 'A1' # Starting node parameter
result = [start]
for each in result:
    if each in graph.keys():
        result.extend(graph[each])
    result = list(set(result))

# Output
print(result)
['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']
```